# OKHTTP request responds with no data

Tags: android, httprequest, okhttp

In my app I make a simple get request via okhttp (this is simplified a bit, but you get the gist)

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .get()
            .build();
try {
    Response response = getOkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
       return response.body().string();
    } else {
            return "";
        }

}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
    return "";
}
```

The url is a http url.

The api is my clients api and the call works fine outside their office network, unfortunately it does not work inside their office network.

Inside their network the response is 200 but there is no data attached to it (`response.body().string()` returns an empty string), however the request works just fine in the browser inside their network.

So what could the difference be between making the request inside their network from the app, versus inside their network in the browser? Could I spoof a browser user agent and that would fix it?

Comment: Using any interceptors?

Comment: No I am not using any interceptors

Answer (score 0):

We do not know what was causing this, apparently their IT department made some sort of unrelated change to the network and now it works.